# Notation clarification on length of strings.

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I am a student who only recently started learning about regular expressions and automatas.

My question involves the following notation: **2|σ| a = |σ| b**
I have read that  **|σ| a** is read as the number of a's in sigma, but I am lost when we equate that to ***|σ| b***.

Does the expression mean "There are 2 **B**'s for every **A**" or "There are 2 **A**'s for every **B**"?

Comment: Twice the number of $a$'s is the number of $b$. So something like $babbcbbaba$ would fit the desciptoin.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, read what you said carefully...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard notation would be $2|\sigma|_a = |\sigma|_b$. Given a word $\sigma$ and a letter $a$, $|\sigma|_a$ denotes the number of occurrences of $a$ in $\sigma$. For instance, if you take the example suggested by Hagen von Eitzen, $\sigma = babbcbbaba$, then you have $|\sigma|_a = 3$ and $|\sigma|_b = 6$, and thus $2|\sigma|_a = |\sigma|_b$.